# Can't find a patch for "CiviCRM is not of type Int"

Tags: issues

CiviCRM 4.6.4/Wordpress.

During API call for Contribution get and parameter id = xxxx, api returns `A fatal error was triggered: CiviCRM is not of the type Int`.

Adding a return statement in `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Query.php` solves the issue but unsure if this will affect other Contribution tasks in production..

Also tried a clean install of 4.6.4 on Wordpress and same issue.

See Line 266:
[image: Adding a return statement on Line 266]

```
{
"trace": "#0 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(269): CRM_Core_Error::fatal('CiviCRM is not ...')\n#1 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(5238): CRM_Utils_Type::escape('CiviCRM', 'Int')\n#2 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Query.php(373): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::buildClause('civicrm_contrib...', '=', 'CiviCRM', 'Int')\n#3 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Query.php(251): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Query::whereClauseSingle(Array, Object(CRM_Contact_BAO_Query))\n#4 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Component.php(298): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Query::where(Object(CRM_Contact_BAO_Query))\n#5 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1894): CRM_Core_Component::alterQuery(Object(CRM_Contact_BAO_Query), 'where')\n#6 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(499): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause()\n#7 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(461): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize()\n#8 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php(595): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct(Array, Array, NULL, false, false, 2, false)\n#9 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Contribution.php(217): _civicrm_api3_get_query_object(Array, 2, 'Contribution')\n#10 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_contribution_get(Array)\n#11 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\\API\\Provider\\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke(Array)\n#12 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\\API\\Kernel->run('Contribution', 'get', Array, NULL)\n#13 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(404): civicrm_api('Contribution', 'get', Array)\n#14 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(640): CRM_Utils_REST::process(Array, Array)\n#15 [internal function]: CRM_Utils_REST::ajax()\n#16 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func(Array)\n#17 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)\n#18 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)\n#19 /vagrant/donate/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1188): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)\n#20 [internal function]: CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')\n#21 /vagrant/donate/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#22 /vagrant/donate/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#23 /vagrant/donate/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#24 /vagrant/donate/wp-admin/admin.php(222): do_action('toplevel_page_C...')\n#25 {main}",
"is_error": 1,
"error_message": "A fatal error was triggered: CiviCRM is not of the type Int"
}
```

The code

```
CRM.api3('Contribution', 'get', {
  "debug": 1,
  "sequential": 1
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Generally, modifying core code is frowned on.  It would be better to include the code leading up to the API call.

Comment: Have you called civicrm_initialize() prior to calling the API?

Comment: The api call is in JS in a blank new civi-native extension. But the same error message is in the API Explorer.

Comment: Good, it's helpful to know that it's happening in the API explorer as well.

Comment: Again, it would be helpful to see the code.  Also, is there anything in the CiviCRM log?  A stack trace would be great if one is available.

Comment: updated the post with the debug

Answer (score 1):

I remember this bug from a long time ago.  I'm pretty positive it's been fixed.

I would try upgrading a copy of your site to the latest 4.6 to see if the problem still exists.  If it doesn't, then upgrading is your solution.

Comment: Jon... it looks like this was a problem before with regard to filtering on contact_id https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16393?jql=project%20%3D%20CRM).  In this case, there are no filters and the error is occuring.

Comment: Yep, tried 4.6.4, 4.6.5, 4.6.9 and same issue. 4.7.0 worked fine. My only issue is that if I want to make my extension public, it will only work for 4.7.0 users. What about LTS users?

Comment: It looks like the fix is in this patch: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5727.  You can test to see if that's true.  If so, I think you should release this for 4.7 only, but in the README mention that 4.6 users can use it if they apply the patch.

Comment: The 4.6.4 core files reflect the code in that patch.. so I'm guessing no one had this api contribution get issue for all of 4.6 until 4.7?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in CiviCRM.  I was able to duplicate it using the API Explorer in the 4.6.29 sandbox.

I note that the 4.7.x version sandbox did not take this error. You should consider updating your version to that.

I did a quick search in CiviCRM's JIRA but could not see such an issue reported.

Comment: Yes, ran a few clean installs and the earliest version that worked is in 4.7.0